# Set up drupal 7 on MAMP and postgresql 9.5

Tags: php, postgresql, drupal, drupal-7, mamp

I am trying to install drupal 7.4 using MAMP and postgresql (9.5.1), I have already created a drupal user and database. I go through the installation steps whilst launching the install.php.

I get the following error after the progress gets stuck at 50%.

Error from postgresql console:

```
ERROR:  currval of sequence "field_config_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
STATEMENT:  SELECT CURRVAL($1)
psql freeswitchERROR:  currval of sequence "field_config_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
STATEMENT:  SELECT CURRVAL($1)
ERROR:  currval of sequence "field_config_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

The drupal installation then halts and a get a link which contains the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "taxonomy_vocabulary" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT name, machine_name, vid FROM taxonomy_vocabulary ^
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong since I already a drupal running successfully on mysql following the same steps.

Please advise.